# How to kill Ant forked process?

Tags: java, ant, process, kill

I have an Ant build file and there is a  task in it. The problem is every time i kill the outer Ant process the forked process is still running out there, so there will be many java process in Windows Task manager, I wonder if there is way when i kill the outer Ant process it will kill all child process at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using "kill process tree" from task manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using "kill process tree will" kill all sub-processes.